# IPTABLES, how to restric that only a specif user to acces from specifics subnets?

Tags: linux, security, iptables

I need to make sure that a specific user only accesses my server from a certain ips
example:
the remoteadmin user, which can only access from the IP ranges 192.168.50. *, 192.168.80. *

Would it also be possible to specify access to certain ports only?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a TCP connection attempt comes in, you normally only know the standard TCP/IP quadlet: source IP, destination IP, source port and destination port. The source port is normally dynamically allocated at the source host, and generally not a reliable indicator of anything.

You don't know for sure who the connecting user might be: to find that out, you must initially accept the connection and perform the authentication procedure, which usually requires some amount of two-way communication. Then, if the username is acceptable *and* the user provided valid authentication credentials, access to the system can be granted. If not, the connection will be cut off after some small number of failed authentication attempts.

`iptables` can certainly restrict access from certain IP ranges to certain ports. But `iptables` cannot know the username associated with the incoming connection, as it must make its decision before the authentication procedure happens.

Any username-based access control decisions must happen within the actual service that handles the authentication for the connection. In other words, if the incoming connection is a SSH connection, then the first thing that will have the capability to make username-based access decisions will be the `sshd` daemon. If `sshd` is configured to use PAM, then PAM rules might also be usable; if `sshd` is compiled to use the `libwrap` library, then `/etc/hosts.allow` and/or `/etc/hosts.deny` might be useful too.

Comment: AFAIK there is a packet tagging facility that you can use. However you need to establish trust between the part-taking network devices in order to rule out that untagged or malicious packets are inserted.